# Visual Studio - Not Recognizing Controls After Certain Point

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am having an issue with Visual Studio. I have a page with a GridView. The code behind recognizes the GridView fine, but none of the elements within it. I tried putting a label before the GridView and it was able to recognize it. This would imply there is some error in my aspx code file, but I have looked it over and all looks well to me.

I have tried deleting .designer.cs file and 'Converting to Web Application'. I have tried copying the code, deleting the files, and recreating them. I have also tried numerous cleans and rebuilds and restarting Visual Studio. Still, no success. I would greatly appreciate any guidance.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="users.aspx.cs" Inherits="Ticket_System.admin.users" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">


    <asp:GridView ID="userGrid" runat="server" OnRowEditing="userGrid_RowEditing" DataKeyNames="END_USER_ID" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowUpdating="userGrid_RowUpdating" OnRowCancelingEdit="userGrid_RowCancelingEdit">

        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User #">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="idLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("END_USER_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="idText" runat="server" Enabled="false" Text='<%# Bind("END_USER_ID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Access">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="accessLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ACCESS_ROLE.DESCRIPTION") %>'></asp:Label>

                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="userLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("USER_NAME") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="userText" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("USER_NAME") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Password">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="passLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PASSWORD") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="passText" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PASSWORD") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="firstLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FIRST_NAME") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="firstText" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FIRST_NAME") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lastLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LAST_NAME") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="lastText" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LAST_NAME") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="activeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ACTIVE_FLAG") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="activeText" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ACTIVE_FLAG") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

</asp:Content>
```

EDIT: Just wanted to clarify something. What I mean is that the controls are not even recognized at all in the code behind. For example `firstLabel.Text` gives me an "does not exist in current context" error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the FindControl() method.

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in userGrid.Rows) {
    if(row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        string idText = (string)row.FindControl("idText");
    }
}
```